# Popup on exiting the page Javascript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to display a feed back pop-up to the user if he/she exits (close the window/close the tab) the page. Same should work if he/she clicks on third party links (any other host) on the page as well but not the self links (belong to the same host). I have tried window.onbeforeunload which seems to work on IE exit only. Could someone help me with this?

Thanks,
Racky

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686687/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-in-javascript-onbeforeunload-event

Answer (score 2):

Use the `unload()` event:

http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Here's the example taken from that page:

```
$(window).unload( function () { alert("Bye now!"); } );
```

This will called when you refresh the page, because technically you aren't submitting it, you are asking for it again, which means you're leaving the one you're on.

Self links shouldn't cause a reload of the page so you'll be fine.  Self links either need to be `#anchorname` or `doSomeJavaScript(); return false;`

Comment: well, thanks for this, but this one is true for self links as well :(

Comment: Anyone? onunload is called even when i refresh the page :(

Comment: It **would** be called when you refresh the page, because technically you aren't submitting it, you are asking for it again, which means you're leaving the one you're on.  Self links shouldn't cause a reload of the page so you'll be fine.  Self links either need to be `#anchorname` or `doSomeJavaScript(); return false;`