# When window.onbeforeunload is called, can I know where the page is being redirected to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Whenever I add an event listener `window.onbeforeunload`, can I check where the page is being redirected to?
Or at least what the developer is trying to change.

The following is the thing that I really want:

This is what I do right now :

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload",function(){
      //I do what I want here
});
```

Now the issue is, I want to change the logic, when `document.location.href = "mailTo:*"` is being called. i.e. I do not want to do anything when `doccument.location.href` is called, so I want my logic to me like:

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload",function(){
       if(document.location.href has mailTo:)
       {
            //do nothing
       }
       else
       {
            //my old logic applies here
       }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to add an event handler to Href links in your webpage,
which set a variable on onclick = their href, you can read that variable in your onbeforeunload script. example code would be like this :

```
  var storeHref = null;
    $("a").bind("click", function(){
      storeHref = this.href;
      return true;
    });

  $(window).bind("beforeunload",function(){
       if(storeHref has mailTo:)
       {
            //do nothing
       }
       else
       {
            //my old logic applies here
       }
  });
```

However if the redirection is happening due to some other event,like user entering a new url in the browser, or using a script, you can not detect the destination due to security reasons.

Similar:
[How can i get the destination url in javascript onbeforeunload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686687/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-in-javascript-onbeforeunload-event)

Comment: the case here actually is not the user clicking a link, but the developer calling document.location.href="mailTo", or document.location.href="someotherlink"

Comment: that seems not possible then, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686687/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-in-javascript-onbeforeunload-event

Comment: can you please update the answer so that I can accept it as the correct one?