# How to identify only browser close event not refresh button

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I want to make user logout when user closes the browser tab/window

I have tried this code, but this is hitting even when we refresh the browser

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     return "Are you sure to close without logout";
     };
```

Is there any method to call the event only when user closes the browser tab/window other than refreshing the browser??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453741/javascript-beforeunload-detect-refresh-versus-close