# Detect if a users closes a web page, but allow refreshes

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, browser

I have a web chat application made with NextJS, and I wanna kick the user from chat when close tab, but no action when user refresh tab. How can I achieve this? There has to be a solution for mobile too?

Comment: Refer this duplicate -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453741/javascript-beforeunload-detect-refresh-versus-close

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript beforeunload detect refresh versus close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453741/javascript-beforeunload-detect-refresh-versus-close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a chat app, you're almost certainly using websockets.  Kick the user from chat (say) a minute after their socket closes if they have no other active sockets.

On the server, monitor the opening and closing of websockets for each user. When a user opens a websocket, associate that socket with the user in the server's memory. When a user closes a websocket (which could be a result of either the user closing the page/browser, or refreshing their page), check if they have any other active sockets. If not, set a timeout for, say, a minute from now. When that minute is up, check if the user still has no active sockets. If not, then they haven't refreshed the page; they've closed it completely, so kick them. If so, then they've reconnected and shouldn't be kicked.

Also clear the timeout associated with the user any time that user connects a new websocket.