# is it possible to only fire window.onbeforeunload if requested url is not var

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload, window.location

Currently

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
```

fires every time i exit the page, is it possible to get the requested `window.location` from a link and if the URL is not the value of a variable run the `window.onbeforeunload = function()`.

Comment: It's not possible. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686687/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-in-javascript-onbeforeunload-event

Comment: ... Unless perhaps instead of using the `onbeforeunload` event, you bind to `a` elements and check their `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the `onbeforeunload` if the loaded url is not equal to variable. But you cant oprevent the attached function's execution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.href!=myvar)
{
 window.onbeforeunload=function(){};
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thats great how about all the variables in an array?

Answer (score 0):

ahren is right here

```
function experiment() {

  experimentEnviroment();
  $('a').click(function(){

    var regestedPage = $(this).attr("href");
    var myvar = "bsc.html"

        if( regestedPage != myvar ) {
            $(this).bind('ready',windowUnload());
        }

  });
 }
```