# Detect non-http redirects using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Can I detect a redirection happening in a browser, which is not pointed to HTTP(s) protocol?

For example, my script redirects to something like ftp://, sms://, ws:// using

```
location.href=ws://abc/a
```

Is there a way to detect such redirection using JS? If useful, I can involve chrome ext environment in this as well.

Comment: I would suggest using onbeforeunload event; unfortunately i don't think this is easily achieved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686687/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-in-javascript-onbeforeunload-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this is not straight away, if you are using chrome extension, you can rely on `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.*` API which would give some clue via `responseHeaders` and you can detect the non-http redirects and setup actions accordingly.