# Get request URL in JS and prevent widow.unbeforeunload

Tags: javascript

I have a `window.unbeforeunload` event and I don't want to fire it if user clicks on logout.

Is there a way to get a request URL in JS before doing its action? My idea is to check if, for example, url is `https://www.example.com/logout` then don't show alert box in `window.unbeforeunload` event.

Comment: `clicks on logout` - put a click even handler on that logout element - set a flag when it's clicked ... check the flag in `beforeunload` handler ...messy, but quick

Comment: Related: [How can I get the destination URL for the onbeforeunload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686687/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-for-the-onbeforeunload-event)